# Optimize A Messy Query

Tags: mysql, performance, database-optimization

So I have this unholy query, and need to clean it up, as it takes ~2 minutes to execute. I can't change any table structure, but I can split it up into sub queries in loops, etc. I'm using C++ and MySQL.

Basically tag(s) are selected, and any user who has a union with the tag must then be selected by the query.

Here is the query, with 123 being a CSV tag id list of length >= 1, and the josh@test.com being a CSV email list of emails to ignore, of length >= 0. I know this is asking a lot, but any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT user_id,user_primaryemail,USER_EMAIL_IS_VALID
FROM users
WHERE ( ( user_id IN ( SELECT union_target_id
                       FROM systemtag_union
                       WHERE union_systemtag_id IN ( '123' )
                         && union_type = 'User'
                       GROUP BY union_target_id
                       HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT union_systemtag_id) = 0) ) )
  && user_primaryemail NOT IN ( 'josh@test.com' )
  && USER_EMAIL_IS_VALID != 'No'
GROUP BY user_primaryemail
```

Rough table structure:

```
users
-----
user_id
user_primaryemail
user_email_is_valid

systemtags
-----
systemtag_id

systemtag_union
-----
union_systemtag_id (corresponds to systemtags.systemtag_id)
union_target_id (corresponds, in this case, to users.user_id)
union_type (the type of the union, irrelevant in this case)
```

EDIT: Here is the result of EXPLAIN, as a CSV:

```
"id","select_type","table","type","possible_keys","key","key_len","ref","rows","Extra"
1,"PRIMARY","users","ALL","user_email","","","",9104,"Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort"
2,"DEPENDENT SUBQUERY","systemtag_union","index","union_systemtag_id,union_type","union_target_id","4","",8,"Using where"
```

Comment: Are any of your tables on the database indexed?

Comment: Could you please share how the tables are indexed, as well as the results of `EXPLAIN SELECT...`? That would be most helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Just as a stab in the dark, I would expect `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT...)` to be a big part of the problem. This phrase is going to force a lot of materialization and sorting while running the query.

Comment: @Paul: user_id, systemtag_id, and the not listed union_id are all unique autoinc primary keys.

Comment: @Wiseguy, I'll run that right now. Just prepend EXPLAIN to the query?

Comment: @Josh Yep. `EXPLAIN {query}` will give the execution plan (how it will join, what keys it will use, etc.).

Comment: @Wiseguy: I've ran it, and added the outcome to my edit.

Comment: What this has to do with c++?

Comment: @VJo: Just the language I'm calling MySQL in, I suppose it's not terribly relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up doing was twofold. I added indexes and reoptimized my tables, which helped a bit, then I completely extracted the systemtag subquery, and stored it in a variable, which I then plugged into the bigger query. Even though the subquery only took .2 seconds, it must have been executing for each iteration of the 20k user database. Thanks so much to all of you, your guidance was indispensable.

Answer (score 2):

As opposed to an actual answer, but more of a detailed question clarification...  Your inner query appears to be querying for (paraphrasing here)

Any User ID that is in the SystemTag_Union table that HAS one or more of the listed tags, yet the count of distinct tags = 0.

This sounds like an oxy-moron... give me something that has one of these tags, but the count of tags = 0... which is it...  In order to qualify, the must have one to meet the WHERE clause.

Can you clarify what the final intent is of this querying?  Are you trying to look for those users who may (or not) have certain tags associated with them that you'll act upon?

I would actually change the query to using distinct such as

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      U.user_id,
      U.user_primaryemail,
      U.USER_EMAIL_IS_VALID
   FROM 
      users U
         JOIN systemtag_union STU
            ON U.User_ID = STU.union_target_id
           AND STU.Union_Type = 'User'
           AND STU.union_systemtag_id IN ( '123' )
   WHERE 
          U.USER_EMAIL_IS_VALID != 'No'
      AND U.user_primaryemail NOT IN ( 'josh@test.com' )
```

Comment: As you say, this isn't a complete answer (but is too long for a comment). So @Josh, please post your detailed response to this as an update to your question. That way it's in a visible spot and this non-answer can safely be removed afterward if applicable. Thanks.